# Why can't I view a git object in an ordinary file editor?

Tags: git

When I run `git cat-file -p <hash>`, I get the content of this object printed rather nicely. When I'm looking for that file in the `.git`-directory manually and open it in my file editor (like notepad), I get only garbage.

Why is that?

Comment: It's probably compressed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because Git [compresses objects](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects#Object-Storage) (*blobs*) for storage and you are looking at the compressed version when you open the file directly in an editor:

> Git compresses the new content with zlib

[zlib](https://github.com/madler/zlib) is a:

> general purpose data compression library

Also from [zlib's Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zlib#Applications):

> The Git version control system uses zlib to store the contents of its
>   data objects (blobs, trees, commits and tags).

The [`cat-file`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cat-file) command is simply showing you the human-readable version of the object:

> In its first form, the command provides the content

Comment: In addition, *commit* and *blob* objects are simply compressed from what you see if you `git cat-file -p` the commit or blob (well, `git cat-file -p` also strips off the header).  But *tree* objects are stored in a binary format.  Both `cat-file` and `show` (e.g., `git show HEAD:path/to/file`) can be used to make any object viewable.